# AjaxToolKit: Balloon Popup Extender on html5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, html5-canvas, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a canvas drawing implemented on my project. I would like to show speech-bubbles with information related to specific mouse clicks on the canvas. Say a click on a particular region of my canvas allows for a popup that gives text information about that region on the canvas.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>


<ajaxToolkit:BalloonPopupExtender ID="BalloonPopupExtender1" 
    runat="server"  
    TargetControlID="myCanvas" 
    BalloonPopupControlID="Panel1"
    Position="TopLeft" 
    BalloonStyle="Cloud"
    BalloonSize="Small"
    CustomCssUrl="CustomStyle/BalloonPopupOvalStyle.css"
    CustomClassName="oval"
    UseShadow="true" 
    ScrollBars="Auto"
    DisplayOnMouseOver="true"
    DisplayOnFocus="false"
    DisplayOnClick="true" />

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="915" height="850" style="border: 2px double #000000;"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

However this doesn't work, I believe this is because myCanvas is not a asp.net/server side element, hence runat ="server" isn't correct methodology.

I am currently following these blogs:-

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/364074/balloonpopupextendercontrol-in-ajax/

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/BalloonPopup/BalloonPopupExtender.aspx

Any idea how to implement the popup on the canvas, upon a click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you want to respond to clicks on specific canvas coordinates, you might have to work on the client side.  Here's code to do an info popup on the client side.

[image]

This is code that will draw an info balloon inside a *separate* canvas element.  The canvas is moved off-screen until it's needed.  You can of course, style this popup balloon *in any way you want* because it's a canvas element!

```
<canvas id="balloon" width=105 height=105></canvas>

function drawBalloon(X,Y,theInfo){
    popCtx.save();
    popCtx.fillStyle="#FD0";
    popCtx.strokeStyle="#000";
    // draw the balloon
    popCtx.beginPath();
    popCtx.moveTo(52,02);
    popCtx.quadraticCurveTo(02,02,02,42);
    popCtx.quadraticCurveTo(02,77,27,77);
    popCtx.quadraticCurveTo(27,102,07,102);
    popCtx.quadraticCurveTo(37,102,42,77);
    popCtx.quadraticCurveTo(102,77,102,42);
    popCtx.quadraticCurveTo(102,02,52,02);
    popCtx.lineWidth=3;
    popCtx.stroke();
    popCtx.fill();
    // draw theInfo
    popCtx.font="10pt arial";
    popCtx.fillStyle="black";
    popCtx.fillText(theInfo,10,50);
    popCtx.restore();
    // move the balloon canvas to the target
    $("#balloon").css({left:offsetX+X, top:offsetY+Y});
}
```

If you're not used to client-side javascript, here's how to get the position of the target-filled canvas relative to the window

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>

// get the position of canvas relative to window
var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
```

And here's how to listen for clicks on the target-filled canvas.

```
// listen for clicks on the canvas
$("#canvas").click(function(e){ 

    // get the mouseclick position
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

    // see if we clicked on any targets, show the balloon
    for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
        var circle=circles[i];
        var dx=circle.x-mouseX;
        var dy=circle.x-mouseY;
        var radius=circle.radius;
        // true if we clicked in the target circle
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<=radius*radius){
            drawBalloon(circles[i].x+radius,circles[i].y-100,circles[i].info);
        }
    }
});
```

To test if any target location on the canvas was clicked, we can test a circular area around the target like this:

```
    var dx=targetCircle.x-mouseX;
    var dy=targetCircle.x-mouseY;
    var radius=targetCircle.radius;
    // true if we clicked in the target circle
    if(dx*dx+dy*dy<=radius*radius){
        // we hit a target, display the balloon
    }
```

Here is working example code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/AJvkN/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px;padding-top:100px; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    #balloon{ position:absolute; left:-200px; }
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    // get reference to our drawing canvas
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    // get reference to our balloon canvas
    var balloon=document.getElementById("balloon");
    var popCtx=balloon.getContext("2d");

    // get the position of canvas relative to window
    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    // define some targets and their basic info
    var circles=[];
    circles.push({x:40,  y:30, radius:15,color:"red",  info:"I'm red."});
    circles.push({x:150, y:150,radius:25,color:"green",info:"I'm centered."});
    circles.push({x:110, y:85, radius:40,color:"blue", info:"I'm big."});

    // draw the target circles on the canvas
    for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
        drawCircle(circles[i]);
    }

    // listen for clicks on the canvas and show the balloon
    $("#canvas").click(function(e){ 

        // get the mouseclick position
        mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

        // see if we clicked on any targets
        for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
            var circle=circles[i];
            var dx=circle.x-mouseX;
            var dy=circle.x-mouseY;
            var radius=circle.radius;
            // true if we clicked in the target circle
            if(dx*dx+dy*dy<=radius*radius){
                drawBalloon(circles[i].x+radius,circles[i].y-100,circles[i].info);
            }
        }
    });


    // listen for clicks on the balloon and then hide the balloon
    $("#balloon").click(function hideBalloon(e){ $("#balloon").css({left:-200}); });


    function drawCircle(circle){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle=circle.color;
        ctx.strokeStyle="black";
        ctx.lineWidth=3;
        ctx.arc(circle.x,circle.y,circle.radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }


    function drawBalloon(X,Y,theInfo){
        popCtx.save();
        popCtx.fillStyle="#FD0";
        popCtx.strokeStyle="#000";
        // draw the balloon
        popCtx.beginPath();
        popCtx.moveTo(52,02);
        popCtx.quadraticCurveTo(02,02,02,42);
        popCtx.quadraticCurveTo(02,77,27,77);
        popCtx.quadraticCurveTo(27,102,07,102);
        popCtx.quadraticCurveTo(37,102,42,77);
        popCtx.quadraticCurveTo(102,77,102,42);
        popCtx.quadraticCurveTo(102,02,52,02);
        popCtx.lineWidth=3;
        popCtx.stroke();
        popCtx.fill();
        // draw theInfo
        popCtx.font="10pt arial";
        popCtx.fillStyle="black";
        popCtx.fillText(theInfo,10,50);
        popCtx.restore();
        // move the balloon canvas to the target
        $("#balloon").css({left:offsetX+X, top:offsetY+Y});
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Click circles to popup an info balloon</p>
    <p>When info balloon appears, click it do dismiss it</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
    <canvas id="balloon" width=105 height=105></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: awesome. I did have the way to figure out canvas click and co-ordinates figured out. basically my canvas is a timeline with historical events. Now when the user clicks on an event, I want to display more information about that event/s. Thanks !

Comment: Hey MarkE, I can't redesign my balloon the way you had showed me:-

http://jsfiddle.net/wCnhv/2/



I am trying to emulate this:-
http://www.scriptol.com/html5/canvas/speech-bubble.php

but failing miserably. Can you help? I want to make a bigger balloon so as to fit more data in it.

Comment: this model, doesn't seem to work with my model.

http://jsfiddle.net/PpLMb/1/

my problem is that, I Want to make my bubble bigger, so I can fit more information in it. I tried using end of line characters (\n\r)... but that don't work either. :((

Comment: also, when I tried to include your model with my previous model, the speech bubble only shows up partially.

Comment: I adjusted my fiddle to make it simpler for you.  The bubble is resizable vertically and horizontally.  You pass in the bubble canvas which must be resized to reflect the new bubble size.  The bubble "flare" is exactly half the bubble's height so when you position your bubble it should align with your hit area.  Canvas text does not have a newline character so you must measure the accumulated text length...if the next word will run off the right edge, you should move the Y-position downward and start a new fillText.  You can use context.measureText("abc def").width to measure your text width.